MongoDB: Efficiently implement TTL index
I currently have the following data model in my mongodb which I have set up accordingly to the problem explained here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/schema-suggestions/avoid-unbounded-arrays/:
DocumentMeta: {
 id: 123,
 createdAt: '$$NOW'
}
DocumentRow : {
 id: set by Mongo,
 metaId: 123
 someDataField: 'xyz',
 createdAt: '$$NOW'
}

Now I have a collection ABC that has exactly one "DocumentMeta" and an arbitrary number of "DocumentRow"
I also have set up a TTL-Index that listens to the createdAt fields and deletes all the Documents in the collection ABC like so:
collection.createIndex({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: _ttlvalue })
My requirement is that the data gets deleted after a certain amount of time of inactivity. By inactivity I mean that really nothing has happened, i.e. no data has been pulled from the mongodb, no parts of the collection has been deleted or added, etc. ...
However, in the case of activity, I want to refresh the TTL of all the documents, i.e. to reset the TTL to '$$NOW' whenever there's an interaction. Currently I do it like this:
  mongodbClient
    .db('db')
    .collection('ABC')
    .updateMany(
      {},
      { $set: { 'createdAt': now} }
  );

Unfortunately, this approach gets slower, the more documents are coming into the collection.
Therefore my question: Is there a more efficient way to update the TTL of documents?
If I could set a TTL for the whole collection that would be perfect. But I haven't any information on how to set a TTL for a collection yet.
And another more efficient way to update all the createdAt fields doesn't come to mind.
Appreciate any ideas! Thanks!
